# Window.print not working for print graph

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc, printing

I have one page where I use java script and css to show graph.When I try to print graph using div content and opening new window it does not work.
Below is screenshot of graph page and print window

[image: My graph page]

[image: Print window graph]

I have tried to put css before printing and also added bootstrap js but stil not work.
Below is code that I copy form stackoverflow and modify as I require.Thanks.

```
 function printDiv() {
        debugger;

        var printContents = $('body').clone().find('script').remove().end().html();

        // get all <links> and remove all the <script>'s from the header that could run on the new window
        var allLinks = $('head').clone().find('script').remove().end().html();

        var js = "";
                        js += "@Html.Raw(string.Format("<script src='/SkillsAssessmentModule/Scripts/bootbox.min.js'/>"))";
       // open a new window
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');
        // ready for writing
        popupWin.document.open();

        // -webkit-print-color-adjust to keep colors for the printing version
        var keepColors = '<style>body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; }</style>';

        // writing
        // onload="window.print()" to print straigthaway
        popupWin.document.write('<html><head>' + keepColors + allLinks + '</head><body>' + document.getElementById("lProgress").innerHTML + js + '</body></html>');
        popupWin.print();
        // close for writing
        popupWin.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () { popupWin.close(); }, 1);
    }
</script>
```

}

Comment: well does the print code let the JavaScript run that makes the graph? Also with CSS Print Media, there is really no reason you need to open a pop up window if the graph is already on the page.

Comment: The graph is already on page but I think print functionality only allow inline css not external css thats why its show me blank at the place of bar graph

Comment: No, that's not correct. Print styles are applied from all applicable CSS, external or not. If the graph exists on the page, but does not print, it's either because it's being hidden in some way by your print-related CSS or you're utilizing a background image to show the graph (background images do not print in most browsers).

Comment: not using any image to show graph.

Comment: The window that I am opening before print window show all bar graph but in print window its blank.It also have all css and js.window with name "popupWin" in above code..